# trying to compare dates using If function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Using the IF function I am trying to return a value if two months match i.e. basically `=IF(A2=$B$1,A4,"")`.

Cell A2 has the date typed in, B1 is `=TODAY()`, both are formatted to show the month which they do and appear to match, so should return the A4 value, but it doesn’t.

What am I doing wrong (I assume it something to do with the formatting)?

Answer (score 2):

when formatting the date Excel still sees the date as a the number of days since 1/1/1900.

Just because the cell shows `June` excel sees `43265` for today.

So unless the date in A2 is today's date it will not be equal.

To compare the months use `MONTH` which returns the month number:

```
=IF(MONTH(A2)=MONTH($B$1),A4,"")
```

Comment: Cheers worked perfectly and has given me a few more ideas

Comment: That should be the number of days since 1900-1-***0*** ;-)